# Using Database tables fundamentally wrong

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

the whole concept of my practice project is to have a professor review system. Where I can manually enter a professor and department into one table which would then allow users to search for said professor. However I'm using that category table just for names and department as a uneditable hard-coded pool of names and departments for selection. Then taking what ever they choose and showing a form with name/department field pre populated with that selection option along with blank fields with the rest of the rest of the attributes from my professor table. Thus rendering category as a merely a vehicle to get to my professor table. Each professor is going to have multiple reviews so how should I efficiently structure this tables in order to achieve normalization?

### category table

- professorid  smallint(6)(PK)
- Description  varchar(40)
- depart   varchar(50)

### professor table

- professorid  smallint(6)
- rating   smallint(6)
- easiness     smallint(6)
- textbook     varchar(3)
- timestamp    timestamp
- course   char(10)
- curve   char(3)
- comment  tinytext

Comment: is your category/professor relation a one-to-many or many-to-many?

Comment: I should add I didn't use a index in the professor table because I knew reviews might repeat in some form. 1 to many I think.

Comment: also, is your professor table the review table?

Comment: Yes professor is my review table

Answer (score 0):

You you should remove some attributes from the professor table and move that to a new review table. I would include

- Rating
- Easiness
- Comment
- Curve

in the review table. It would probably be wise to create a course table.

Comment: you should look up partial dependency